# How can I create an ODBC connection to SAS?

Tags: python, sas, odbc

I'm writing a program that needs to access SAS data.  I've downloaded the ODBC drivers for SAS and installed them, but I need to be able to create ODBC connections on the fly, programmatically.  The following code (in Python) seems like it should work:

```
import ctypes

ODBC_ADD_DSN = 1        

def add_dsn(name, driver, **kw):
    nul, attrib = chr(0), []
    kw['DSN'] = name
    for attr, val in kw.iteritems():
        attrib.append('%s=%s' % (attr, val))

    return ctypes.windll.ODBCCP32.SQLConfigDataSource(0, ODBC_ADD_DSN, driver, nul.join(attrib)) == 1

print add_dsn('SAS Test', 'SAS', description = 'Testing SAS')
```

But it pops up the SAS ODBC configuration dialog, sets the datasource name, and waits for the user to enter the information and dismiss the dialog.  How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 3):

In order to get ODBC access to SAS data, you need to connect to a running SAS session of some kind; you can't access SAS data table files directly with the SAS ODBC drivers.

See the [SAS ODBC drivers guide](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/odbcdref/61927/PDF/default/odbcdref.pdf), section "What Software Do I Need?".

Your question doesn't state that you are trying to access SAS data through a running SAS product. The SAS ODBC drivers guide should tell you how to set up the connection based on the SAS product you will make the connection through.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is ancient but it probably comes up often enough that I will share the answer I know. The easiest way to achieve what you are trying to do is create what's called a "DSN-Less Connection."

Briefly, you create a connect string that you use when opening a connection, that identifies the driver and includes all the parameters you'd normally fill in in creating a DSN for that driver.

This technique has been around for a very long time-- I was using it in 2001, and it's older than that.

Here is a series of sample DSN-Less connection strings for accessing SAS data via ODBC:

Using Server ID
`Provider=sas.ShareProvider;Data Source=shr1;`

SAS/SHARE
Using Server ID and node (network name)
Provider=sas.ShareProvider;Data Source=shr1;Location=lambchop.unx.sas.com;

SAS/SHARE
Specifying user and password
`Provider=sas.ShareProvider;Data Source=shr1;Location=lambchop.unx.sas.com;
User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;`

SAS/SHARE
Server requires a password
`Provider=sas.ShareProvider;Data Source=shr1;Location=lambchop.unx.sas.com;
User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
SAS Server Access Password=myServerPassword;`

These are from:
https://www.connectionstrings.com/sas-share/

A SAS support page discusses this more-- I found it here:
http://docslide.us/documents/opening-an-ado-connection-object.html

Answer (score 0):

I know zilch about SAS, but the function used to connect to a database on the fly in ODBC is [SQLDriverConnect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms715433%28VS.85%29.aspx). You don't need (or want) to add a DSN, you just need the drivers installed.