# How to access SAS dataset (available both n local derive and SAS server) from Python code?

Tags: python, sas, dataset

I am writing some code in Python with all the data available in SAS datasets both on Local hard drive and SAS server. The problem is how to access / import these datasets directly in my python program and then write back? Can anybody help. I have seen recommendation for python package "Sas7bdat" but not sure about it. is there anyway other way to get connected especially to the datasets available on the local derive (not on server)?

Comment: For simply accessing the data, `Sas7bdat` might be enough. But to establish a read/write connection, look into ODBC connections which, once properly set up, will give you much more power and flexibility. Look for `SAS ODBC Drivers` and a Python module which would allow you to connect to that source. Check out this related post which *might* give you some cues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357547/how-can-i-create-an-odbc-connection-to-sas

Comment: why you are not sure about `Sas7bdat` ?

Comment: Thanks all for the reply, basically I am trying to use the sas7bdat package but I am unable to get connected. Code I am using is below:    <pre><code>    >>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('H:\Desktop\Python\sas7bdat-2.0.7')
>>> from sas7bdat import sas7bdat


ImportError: No module named six
>>>    <pre> <code>    <br/>   I am basically new to python so may be doing something wrong but not sure where m I doing the mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of sas7bdat package you can access all sas datasets normally in local drive, and to use datasets from server use FTP or SFTP connections to read the file as a object and it's easy to access.